# Why INT(11) when it only stores 10 digits?

Tags: mysql, sql, int

I know that the number inside parenthesis does not control the storage limit; but I am curious why it is popular to write `INT(11)` when it only stores 10 digits (unsigned 4,294,967,295). Using numbers smaller than the capacity like `tinyint(1)` is understandable but why higher?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A signed integer is 11: 10 digits + 1 sign

An unsigned integer is 10.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the 11 counts the sign digit

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with the INT type, the "size" is the display size. An INT is 4 bytes.

The extra (10 + 1) is for the minus sign. If you make it an unsigned int, the size will default to 10 instead of 11.

There would be no reason to go beyond 11.